# select()-able timers

Tags: c, linux, select, system-calls

select() is a great system call. You can pack any number of file descriptors, socket descriptors, pipes, etc. and get notified in a synchronous fashion when input becomes available.

Is there a way to create an interval/oneshot timer and use it with select()? That would save me from having multiple threads for IO and timing.

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of timer you want? `select()` has standard timeout parameter.

Comment: The timer parameter is used internally by select(). If select() hasn't gotten any pending read/write/err before that timeout, then it will return. What I am looking for is a command to turn a timer into a filedescriptor and pack it into the fd_set.

Comment: The select timeout parameter is just for timeouts if there's no other events, it's quite some work to build several interval timers and oneshot timers on top of that

Comment: In relation to "You can pack any number of file descriptors, socket descriptors, pipes"... that's somewhat incorrect. `select` starts to break down when the value of an `fd` is over 1023. See [here](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html)...
I would consider `kqueue` on BSD like systems, `epoll` on Linux based systems and Overlapped IO on windows based systems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[timerfd_create](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) does exactly this. It's a fairly recent addition to the linux kernel and might not be available on all distros yet though.

Comment: Wow.. How did I not know about this? I must brush up on my linux syscalls.

Comment: THere's a signalfd call too, in case you want signals delivered as fd events as well :-)

Answer (score 7):

Use the timeout parameter - keep your timer events in a priority queue, check the top item and set the timeout accordingly - if the timeout is reached, then you can check that the event is ready to run, run the event and continue.

At least that's what I do.

Note that poll has a nicer interface (in some ways) and may be more efficient with lots of file descriptors.

Comment: +1 thanks Mark. Do you have any pointer to sample code or FOSS using the trick that you suggested?

Answer (score 2):

MarkR has a nice portable solution, but here's another:

Use a POSIX timer (`timer_create`) and you can transform the problem into "`select`-able signals". This problem has a classic solution: writing to a pipe from the signal handler and `select`ing on the read end of the pipe.

Comment: Wow, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Building on @MarkR, using a sorted structure to store callback+closure with an int and a pointer to an int.  If the two ints have the same value then the event is active otherwise it was discarded.

This way events can be discarded simply by increasing an int.  Perhaps not the most straightforward solution but it was all I could think of.

https://github.com/cheako/tor2web/tree/6ac67f80daaea01d14a5d07e6026e1af4258dc96/src

```
hextree.c contains the code for the data structure used.
schedule.c:156 is where the int is changed.
gnutls.c:197 is where the timers are created.
```