# Implementing timer using select

Tags: sockets, select, timer

I am planning to write a small timer library in C using `timerfd_create`.

The basic user of this library will have two threads

- application thread
- Timer thread

There will be a queue between these two threads so that whenever the application wants to start a timer, it will push a message into the queue which the timer thread will then read and create an FD for it and put it in `select`.

The problem with the above approach is that the timer thread being a single thread would be blocked in the `select` system call and would not know if a message has been posted in his receive queue to start a timer.

One way around this is to let the select timeout every "tick" and then check for messages in the queue. Is their a better way to do this?
I was also thinking of raising an Interrupt every time the application puts a message in the `select` queue to interrupt the `select`. Does that work well with Multi-threaded applications?

Platform : Unix

Comment: How are you planning on the timer and application threads interacting?

Comment: through queues between the two threads

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2328127/1153319

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on having multiple threads post timers to a dedicated timer thread sitting in `select(2)`, then why not use [`eventfd(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) or just an old-good [self-pipe trick](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html) to signal that new timers are available. Include the event file descriptor to the pollable set, wait on all of them.

Comment: that sounds interesting. I'll take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which platform(s) are you wanting to target?  Under Windows, for instance, there are much better ways to handle this without using select(), such as PostThreadMessage() and WaitMessage().

Comment: its Unix. I will add that to the question

Comment: It's obviously Linux, since `timerfd_create(2)` is Linux-specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using timerfd's then there is no need for a dedicated timer thread, just write the application around an event loop using `select`, `poll`, or `epoll`, etc.

Comment: the actual application has 3 threads all of which can issue timer requests at any time.